# Convert string/varchar to date between MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, date

I have a large PHP project that I've been working on for my own business.

I have a MySQL table, with about 2600 entries, that I'd like to "fix" the dates in. My current table has 3 VARCHAR columns that contain string dates.  I'd like to convert these, into a duplicate table, but change them to type DATE on the way.

Once I make the conversion and everything looks good, I will copy the new table to the old database, and only allow a date picker to enter those dates on a going-forward basis.

Most of the existing string dates are on the format `mm-dd-yyyy`, example: `05-03-2013`.  Some are `mm/dd/yyyy`, example: `05/03/2013`, and a few are of the MONTH DAY, YEAR format, example: `March 26th, 2013`.

What I ultimately want is them to be of the `yyyy-mm-dd` format, example: `2013-05-02`.

I *think* I can do this using PHP, passing each string date through strtotime() and then date() but was wondering if MySQL can do this directly.

Comment: Try mysql date_format()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET
  new_column = STR_TO_DATE(varchar_date, '%m-%d-%Y')
WHERE
  STR_TO_DATE(varchar_date, '%m-%d-%Y') IS NOT NULL
```

And then the same query, with date format as `'%m/%d/%Y'`, and then again with `'%M %D, %Y'`.
If the format doesn't match, STR_TO_DATE will return NULL and rows won't be updated.

If you wish to insert your existing data to a new table, you could use something like this:

```
INSERT INTO new_table (ID, col1, col2, new_column)
SELECT
  ID, col1, col2,
  COALESCE(STR_TO_DATE(varchar_date, '%m-%d-%Y'),
           STR_TO_DATE(varchar_date, '%m/%d/%Y'),
           STR_TO_DATE(varchar_date, '%M %D, %Y'))
FROM oldtable
```

(new_column is a date column, and you can then format how you want using PHP or using DATE_FORMAT)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('May 1, 2013','%M %d,%Y');
```

Reference:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date